# how to generate woocommerce api consumer key and secret

Tags: woocommerce-rest-api

How do i generate `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret` for `wp_woocommerce_api_keys` from a function call.

So that i can automatically give users read access to woocommerce.

Answer (score 1):

I thought the same thing, but there isnt in core. I think we have to deal with the `update_api_key` Function located in class-wc-ajax.php.

it will be saved in the `wp_woocommerce_api_keys` table.